# How to deal with BufferedImage from servlet to jsp?

Tags: image, jsp, servlets, image-processing, bufferedimage

In my image.jsp, it will display a facebook photo. I can click on some features like "Darken Image" for example.

```
<form name="frmImage" action="image" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="source" value="${param.source}" />
    <input type="submit" value="Darken" name="darken" />
</form>
```

Inside my ImageServlet, I will then do the image processing for darkening the image. I made used of BufferedImage.

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException{

    String source= req.getParameter("source");
    BufferedImage img = null;
    URL url = new URL(source);
    img = ImageIO.read(url);

    if(req.getParameter("darken") != null){
        //do the processing
        this.darkenImage(img);
    }    
    getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/image.jsp").forward(req, resp);
}
```

Now comes the issue, how am I suppose to return back the processed image back to my jsp page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse the chain of steps:

- In the servlet: merely prepare an "image URL" calling a processing servlet with darken/url etc.
- In the JSP an `<img src="imageprocess?param1=...&param2=...">`.
- In the image processing servlet use `ImageIO.write(response.getOutputStream())`.

Whether or not to use the first servlet is your decision.
Do not forget `response.setContentType("image/jpeg");` or so.

Comment: It works, however, it will show me a jsp page with just the processed image. Is it possible to redirect back to the same jsp (image.jsp for my case) so that all the html and everything is still there.

Comment: Yes, that is quite common. In fact I think you have a servlet mapping for "/image" and the form's action is again "image", so comming back. `req.setAttribute(Object)` can be used to pass anything, i.e. the image's src value. In the JSP you can then conditionally show an `<img>`.

Comment: Is it possible to store the processed image in the setAttribute at servlet and retrieve that attribute in jsp page for display? If possible, do you happen to know how is the line of coding for the display in jsp goes like?

Comment: To add-on, actually what I want is for user to darken an image. So it would be nice if the user clicks on the darken button, the image will be darken and displayed on the same spot. If it can be done without loading the servlet side for each click, it would be even better.

Comment: You could do `req.getSession().setAttribute("img", img)` or so. A search with **html5 canvas image effects** will give some interesting client side possibilities.

Comment: The html5 canvas is actually what I want, I will explore it, thanks. Hoping there is no constraint integrating that to my project.